# How to remove/delete foreign key from a table when created in the following format?

Tags: sql-server

```
create table patient_diagnosis(
diagnosis_id decimal(10) identity(1,1),
symptoms varchar(30) not null,
diagnosis_provided varchar(30) not null,
physician_id varchar(10) not null,
plan_id varchar(10) not null,
date_of_diagnosis date not null,
follow_up_required varchar(1),
date_of_follow_up date,
bill_id decimal(10) not null,
foreign key (physician_id, plan_id) references physician(physician_id, plan_id),
foreign key (bill_id) references billing(bill_id));
```

I want to delete foreign key "bill_id" and drop the column from table.
Please reply.

Comment: Is this SQL? What does this have to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

Since the table has unnamed constraint, its name was assigned automatically. So first find the foreign key name:

```
select name from sys.foreign_keys
where [object_id] = object_id('patient_diagnosis')
and parent_object_id = object_id('billing');
```

then drop it:

```
alter table patient_diagnosis drop constraint ...insert name here...;
```